# Stream filter.findfirst

Tags: java, потоки-данных, filter

```
try {
    Stream<String> stringStream = Files.lines(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    stringStream.forEach((String e) -> {
        if (e.contains("12")) {
            System.out.println(path);
            break;   // как остановить работу если нашёл нужное
        }
     });
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

не могу понять как воспользоваться `filter.findfirst` покажите на моём примере

Comment: Опишите подробнее, чего именно вы хотите добиться. Пока видно, что вы пытаетесь использовать стримы в императивном стиле, что в корне неправильно.

Answer (score 1):

Из вопроса не совсем понятно, что хочется, но предположу:

```
Stream<String> stringStream = Files.lines(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
Optional<String> firstStr = stringStream.filter(i -> i.contains("12")).findFirst();
firstStr.ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

Он и так при использовании `filter` и `findFirst` остановится на первом найденном элементе. 
Как проверить? Вот так:

```
Stream<String> stringStream = Stream.of("345", "12", "789", "101112");
Optional<String> found = stringStream.filter(s -> {
        System.out.println(s);
        return s.contains("12");
    }).findFirst();
```

> 345
>
> 12

Если вам нужно дополнительно выводить подходящие под фильтр значения, то рекомендую писать так (в данном случае выведется только "12", поскольку `peek` уже после фильтра стоит):

```
Optional<String> found = stringStream
        .filter(s -> s.contains("12"))
        .peek(System.out::println)
        .findFirst();
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам действительно нужен .filter
А дальше проверяете, если ли что-то в optional.

```
Stream<Integer> stringStream = Arrays.stream(new Integer[]{5, 7, 15 , 7});
Optional<Integer> result = stringStream.filter(integer -> integer == 7).findFirst();
```

Раскрытая лямбда

```
new Predicate<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public boolean test(Integer integer) {
            return integer == 7;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Я так подозреваю, что `path` отвечает за имена файлов, которые просматриваются и если в файле есть искомая подстрока ("12"), то выводится имя этого файла (`path`). Если автор хотел такую логику, то лучше использовать .anyMatch():
Например, есть 3 файла: 1.txt, 2.txt, 3.txt

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        Path path = new File((i + 1) + ".txt").toPath();
        try {
            Stream<String> stringStream = Files.lines(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            if (stringStream.anyMatch(s -> s.contains("12"))) {
                System.out.println(path);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```